# Pre-1978 sci-fi novel involving life under an Asian occupation of US

Tags: story-identification, alternate-history

Just in case: it's not the "Man in the High Castle"! ;) -- which was published much earlier.

This science fiction story (may have been a novella), from what little I recall, involved the aftermath and description of at least a partial occupation of the US by an Asian nation (not certain if Chinese, Japanese, Korean) and resistance/life under occupation. The technology and setting, I believe, is typical 1970s-era (i.e., no spaceships/laser pistols).

This was very probably published in the 1970s, definitely before 1978, and is a relatively obscure title as I have never seen it anywhere (I might not have recognized it if I saw it though)  - not that I've been looking for it but I read SF a lot and scan titles and lists of sci fi books from different eras frequently). I seem to recall it being a bit grittier and more adult (some sexual content) in tone than a typical sci-fi novel for teens.

Comment: This is very little to go on. The trope of America being invaded and occupied by China/Japan/Russia is extremely common; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InvadedStatesOfAmerica

Comment: The description could fit any one of a dozen novels; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternate_history_fiction

Comment: I vaguely remember a story where a scientist at Los Alamos has misgivings about developing the atom bomb.  He takes peyote in the desert with Indians, which causes him to travel forward to a future in which the Japanese and Nazis had conquered the USA.  Does that sound familiar?

Comment: @WillFeldman The one you're thinking of is ["Two Dooms"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40842) by C. M. Kornbluth.

Comment: There was another from Philip K. Dick, but details do not match (in that story, the Asian supervisor turns a blind eye to the American activities because they have found a cure from a illness affecting him).

Comment: The broken Solitude Trilogy by Marvin Kaye and Parke Godwin ([*The Masters of Solitude*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Masters_of_Solitude) and [*Wintermind*](http://www.amazon.com/Wintermind-Solitude-Trilogy-Marvin-Kaye/dp/0385148917)) takes place in a post-Asian-occupation North America, but the tech level is much lower than you describe; it's mostly pre-industrial, with one exception.

Comment: Not Buck Rogers (1928) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Rogers although the Han had conquered America.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/scifi-novel-about-scientists-discovering-alternatives-to-electromagnetism (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: I think I recall this book from the early eighties. The Asian occupiers of America find a guy on a communal farm for some reason connected to the return of an American spaceship that communicates in English. Does that ring any bells?

Comment: I just starting this search and believe we read the same book. I was in high school in early 1970's when I read this novel. I thought it was called "The Lotus Eaters", but cannot find that title from that date. There were some frightening scenarios of forced living in barracks and brutality. Did you find the book you were searching for?

Answer (score 11):

Could it be Heinlein's [The Sixth Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Column) aka The Day After Tomorrow?  This features the United States being conquered by "PanAsians".  It's a bit early, 1949, but it's been reprinted so many times.

The resistance discovers an electro-magnetic-gravitational mumbo-jumbo magic that can do pretty much anything the author wants (hey, it's early Heinlein).  They found a religion (the PanAsians allow free religion) and use their techno-magic to appear as genuine prophets.

Comment: This is mentioned in the Wiki article you link, but note that Sixth Column wasn't an original Heinlein story, it was someone else's story that he reworked, and Heinlein himself wasn't a fan of the finished product.

Comment: Heinlein's The Sixth Column was a reworking of John W. Campbell's All.

Answer (score 7):

I think that's probably [*Arslan*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Arslan-S-F-MASTERWORKS-M-J-Engh/dp/0575095016) (UK title *A Wind from Bukhara*) by [M J Engh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._J._Engh), first published in 1976. It's a somewhat improbable novel in which nomadic tribes from central Asia conquer the world (as they did under Genghis Khan), and their leader establishes his world capital in a small town in Illinois. It's certainly grittier and more sexual than a 1970s teen novel would have been.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of *[Not This August](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_This_August)* by C.M. Kornbluth. It was first published in 1955, but I remember it being republished in the 1980 timeframe ([This version](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?24557), specifically). [Ifsdb entry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1455).

The story opens just after the US has surrendered to Russian and Chinese Communist forces. The protagonist is a farmer, and the first part of the book takes place on his farm as the occupying forces begin converting the country over to a socialist government. Eventually, the protagonist takes on a farm hand who is more than he appears.

One memorable bit from the latter part of the book is that it becomes common to hand someone a penny and say "Christmas Eve".

> The farm hand turns out to be a refugee from a secret local military base, where the US was building a secret weapon. The refugee had killed everyone on the base to protect it from spies, and has PTSD from the events. Eventually, the farmer and another man begin travelling the country as bums, finding people to reopen the base and generally organizing a rebellion. The sign of the rebellion is handing someone a penny and saying "Christmas Eve".